# IPython shell via embed() not showing colors

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

I use the following snippet to drop to an interactive IPython CLI from my code:

```py
from IPython import embed

# do some things

embed()
```

But no syntax highlighting or any other color shows up.

If, in contrast, I start ipython simply with

```
ipython3
```

Then colors show up as expected.

How can I get colors/syntax highlighting when embedding IPython like this?

- `IPython==7.21.0`
- `python3==3.7.5`

Also on [gh issues](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12850)

Answer (score 2):

Has posted on [Github by me](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/12850)

This is a known problem as you can see [here](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/11523)

I suggest you to run your code as follow:

```py
from IPython import embed

# do some things

embed(colors="neutral")
```

The supported colors are (as you can read [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/details.html#terminal-colors)): Neutral, NoColor, LightBG, Linux

Comment: Oh wow, how did I not find this issue... Thanks for the quick answer, that works!  I'll have to wait a couple of hours before I can award the bounty

Comment: I'm happy that this also worked for you! No problem :)